# omniauth-saml as provider in gitlab

Tags: omniauth, saml, gitlab

I'm trying to get omniauth-saml configured, but I'm not entirely sure what I need to put in app_id and app_secret for this configuration.

I'm using this gem: https://github.com/PracticallyGreen/omniauth-saml

If I leave those fields blank, of course I get:

Received wrong number of arguments. [nil, nil]

The documentation within the gitlab.yml file links to more documentation about gitlab and omniauth, but that document no longer exists (redirects to old README).

Any assistance would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Working-Custom-Omniauth-Provider-Configurations#working-cas-configuration

The working CAS configuration shows you how you skip using the standard configuration and just pass the options directly to the provider using devise.rb.  That's how I would configure omniauth-saml as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get SAML working with Gitlab 6.2.4, but it is not the most elegant solution.  I am using Okta as the IdP, but I believe the configuration is sufficiently generic and could be applied to any SAML IdP.

Added `omniauth-saml` to the Gemfile and ran bundle

```
bundle install --without development test postgres --path vendor/bundle --no-deployment
```

Created `GITLAB/config/initializers/omniauth.rb`

```
 Devise.setup do |config|
   config.omniauth :saml,
     idp_cert_fingerprint: "your IdP certificate fingerprint",
     idp_sso_target_url: "your IdP SAML end point"
 end
```

Modified `GITLAB/app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb` (added this following the definition for ldap)

```
def saml
  handle_omniauth
end
```

I had to manually add the callback for SAML as I was getting the same error as the original poster when I tried to properly define SAML as a provider in `gitlab.yml`.  This is the only way I could get Gitlab to start and authenticate via SAML.  This feels very hacky, so there is probably a more elegant way to implement this; however, I could not find an example anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Custom-omniauth-provider-configurations#working-saml-configuration

I managed to get it to work, so I documented the procedure on the GitLab wiki.

**EDIT**: [It seems like SAML is now supported officially.](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/06/22/gitlab-7-12-released/) No Single Logout yet, though… This seems to be an omniauth limitation.